# App was rejected for both using and not using Advertising Identifier

Tags: facebook, cocos2d-x, iad, mixpanel, idfa

Basically, my app does not use ads, but it does use Facebook integration and mixPanel.  I just added mixPanel and when I attempted to submit it I wasn't able to say it didn't use IDFA because:

Your app is using the Advertising Identifier (IDFA). You must either provide details about the IDFA usage or remove it from the app and submit your binary again.

So I submitted it and it was rejected for not making using of the IDFA. I read online that to make this work I had to remove the iAd.framework, but the Facebook framework relies on it so I can't get rid of it.

`_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager`, referenced from:

```
objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdEnvironmentData.o)

objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)
```

Comment: The Facebook framework is an advertising framework. Where do you think you're getting all this free demographics information from? And who do you think you're leaking/sharing all this demographics information from your own app with? That's right, you're sharing all that information with Facebook, which will then share it with many thousands of other advertisers you don't even know about.

Comment: *the Facebook framework relies on it*, the Facebook ad network relies on the iAd framework? Where did you read this?

Comment: When I removed the iAD framework, I started getting the errors:        _OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager, referenced from:

objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdEnvironmentData.o)

objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)

Comment: What version of cocos2d-x and FB sdk are you using? Latest FB SDK doesn't require iAd framework nor ADSupport framework